# How can I make other apps play/pause music?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making a media controller app similar to this example made by google. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller
However, I want to make a function that can resume playing music or pause given package name. I managed to return a list of package names.
PS. I'm using react native that's why I need a fucntion that I can call from the react side.

```java
    public void getMediaApps (Callback callback) {
        // = getPackageManager();
        ArrayList<MediaAppDetails> mediaApps = new ArrayList<MediaAppDetails>();
        Intent mediaBrowserIntent = new Intent(MediaBrowserServiceCompat.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
        List<ResolveInfo> services = packageManager.queryIntentServices(
                    mediaBrowserIntent,
                    PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER
            );
        if (services != null && !services.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : services) {
                mediaApps.add(
                    new MediaAppDetails(info.serviceInfo, packageManager, resources)
                );
            }
        }
        WritableArray waPackagenames = Arguments.createArray();
        // ArrayList<String> packagenames = ArrayList<String>() 
        if(mediaApps != null && !mediaApps.isEmpty()){
            for(MediaAppDetails mediaApp : mediaApps){
                waPackagenames.pushString(mediaApp.packageName);
            }
        }
        callback.invoke(waPackagenames);
    }
```

I've been trying to do this for 3 days now, but no luck.
Probably won't make such of a difference but this is where I got so far with the play function.

```java
@ReactMethod
    public void play (String packageName) {
        PackageManager pm = this.packageManager;
        Resources res = this.resources;
        ServiceInfo serviceInfo = MediaAppDetails.findServiceInfo(packageName, pm);
        mMediaAppDetails = new MediaAppDetails(serviceInfo, pm, res);
        MediaSessionCompat.Token token = mMediaAppDetails.sessionToken;        
        if (token == null) {
            if (mMediaAppDetails.componentName != null) {
                mBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this.reactContext, mMediaAppDetails.componentName,
                        new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected() {
                                setupMediaController();
                                // mBrowseMediaItemsAdapter.setRoot(mBrowser.getRoot());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended() {
                                //TODO(rasekh): shut down browser.
                                // mBrowseMediaItemsAdapter.setRoot(null);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed() {

                                showToastAndFinish("connection failed .. shit!");
                            }

                        }, null);
                        mBrowser.connect();
            } else if (mMediaAppDetails.sessionToken != null) {
                setupMediaController();
            }
            token = mBrowser.getSessionToken();
            Toast.makeText(this.reactContext, "no token can't open controller", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // toast
        }
        // Toast.makeText(this.reactContext, "found token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mBrowser == null )mBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this.reactContext, new ComponentName(packageName, "MainActivity"), null, null);
        MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;
        try{
            mController = new MediaControllerCompat(this.reactContext, token);
            if(mController!= null) {
                transportControls = mController.getTransportControls();
                transportControls.play();
            }
        }catch(Exception E){
            Log.w("Error",E);
            Log.w("Error","couldn't create mediaControllerCompat");
            // System.out.println(E);
            // System.out.println("couldn't create mediaControllerCompat");
        }

    }
```

Comment: you'll probably need to use intents. whether you can do it depends on whether the target app is exposing them for the features you want to control. get the apk for the target app, and extract its AndroidManifest.xml with apktool -- see what kind of intents you can send to it.

Comment: This certainly is a way, but it can't be done dynamically (like how I get the mediaApps). You have to know ahead of time the name of the app using your way

Comment: Yeah. So unless apps all subscribed to a common interface, I don't think you'll be able to do it (without the extra effort), since I believe they can have their own private media player object and control it without sharing it externally. I suspect that apps which control many other audio players: for example, car audio app controlling amazon music, might do this approach and need to do something different for each one. One way to know for sure would be to decompile an app that does what you want and see what's happening.